# Grey background-color on List item instead of white

Tags: material-ui

I'm trying to use Material-ui to make a list but for some reason the list items background color turns grey. I don't understand where this grey color is coming from. According to the docs http://www.material-ui.com/v0.15.0-alpha.1/#/components/list the color of the list items should be white.

```
const muiTheme = getMuiTheme({
  fontFamily: 'Roboto, sans-serif',
  palette: {
    primary1Color: blue500
  }
});

render () {
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={muiTheme}>
      <div>
      <AppBar title='Test' showMenuIconButton={false} />
      <List>
      <Subheader>Heading</Subheader>
      <ListItem primaryText="Nexus"/>
      </List>
      </div>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Image showing background color]

Comment: http://books.andersos.net/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what's causing that gray background - from normalize.css

```
[type=submit], [type=reset], button, html [type=button] {
    -webkit-appearance: button;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As André said, it's in normalize.css (and sanitize.css too!). A way to get around the issue without changing normalize is to put a rule on a parent div. I've got my ListItems in a Drawer, inside a div with this menuDrawer class:

`/* Get around the MaterialUI listItems having a grey background */
.menuDrawer [type="button"] {
  -webkit-appearance:inherit;
}`